# (Ubuntu - Lamp) Why exist in Ubuntu lamp 2 PHP.ini files?

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-10.04, lamp, php.ini

Why exist in Ubuntu lamp 2 PHP.ini files, and what function they doing?

1. **/etc/PHP5/cli/PHP.ini**
2. **/etc/PHP5/apache2/PHP.ini**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first file, `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, is the PHP configuration file (`php.ini`) for when the console command `php` is run. The second file, `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, is the PHP configuration file for when PHP is run as an Apache extension. If you're trying to use a `php.ini` for your website, use the *second* location.

Answer (score 2):

PHP can be executed from the command line or from a webserver. `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is used for the webserver execution, `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is used for the command line execution.

Comment: beat me to it by 39 seconds D:

Comment: Ye I'm so sorry! XD But we're both right! :D